# Should we have a tag for old open problems that have been resolved on this site?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are several relativity old open problems that have been resolved by our community members. One such case is [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/18045/495) which resolved an open problem that was originally posed in 1998.

> Should we have a tag for old open problems that have been resolved on this site?

For example, I suggest resolved-open-problem Tag.

Comment: By old open problems I mean problems known to be open for at lest five years.

Comment: like the idea of bringing attn to these problems but it might make more sense as a web page or blog entry that is updated over time. or maybe just a meta question with new answers? another notable case is the "unshuffling a string" question (which has been blogged about also). alas, these cases seem to be relatively rare on the site.

Comment: see also [original proofs generated on the site](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/784/original-proofs-generated-on-the-parent-site) and [highlights of cstheory](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/383/highlights-of-cstheory-stackexchange-com)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is unnecessary (search with open-problem tag with accepted answer) and not a very useful tag (unlikely to be used for searching).